# Karaf cannot install war feature

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

Recently I need to deploy something on Karaf. I use Karaf 3.0.2 and event try 4.0.0M1. Both are not able to install war feature. Once I type feature:install war in console after Karaf start-up. 
3.0.2 gives me:
Error executing command: Error resolving artifact org.apache.servicemix.specs:org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation-api-1.1:jar:2.2.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.servicemix.specs:org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation-api-1.1:jar:2.2.0
4.0.0M! gives me:
Erroe executing command: Error

I try to delete Maven and reinstall it. The issue is still there. It's not happened on other machine.
It's a strange issue. Could anyone meet it ever? Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

As it works on the other machines, it's something on that certain machine. 
Without much more details on the setup I'm using assumptions here.
1) No Network connection to the central repo
2) Using a Proxy wich isn't configured or configured wrong on the server
3) Using a nexus with credentials and those aren't configured or configured wrong

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and it was because there were mirrors defined in my Maven settings.xml (due to usage in another project). After I commented them out I was able to install the karaf war deployer.